# DTS to AC3 conversion for LG TV using mediatomb DLNA server

Tags: vlc-media-player, ffmpeg, video-streaming, dlna, audio-streaming

I want to convert a MKV video file containing DTS audio to a stream with AC3 audio. I want to pass this resulting stream to mediatomb's transcoding feature. Mediatomb will transfer the stream via DLNA to a LG TV, which does not support DTS audio.

I have tried the VLC command below but the TV does not recognize the stream, and playing the destination stream on PC does not produce sound.

```
vlc -vvv -I dummy INPUT.file --sout \
'#transcode{acodec=ac3,ab=256k,channels=2,threads=4} \
 :std{mux=ts,access=file,dst=DEST.file}'
```

The following ffmpeg command give a stream that plays on the TV with sound, but the ffmpeg process gets killed (with signal 15) within 10-15 seconds, and then the TV restarts the playback from the beginning. This goes on in loops.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.file -acodec ac3 -ab 384k -vcodec copy  \
 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -y DEST.file
```

I want to have a working DLNA server which transcodes DTS to AC3, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact scenario.  Do a Google search for `'mkvdts2ac3'` and use it.  It extracts the DTS audio, timecodes, etc.  It then converts it to AC3 then muxes it back in with the existing video.  Takes about 10 minutes or so on my Corei7 3.4 GHz.

Using it is as simple as this:

`Linux $ mkvdts2ac3.sh Movie.mkv`

The script handles the rest.

Comment: When I say exact, I mean I have an LG 42" TV and I serve up media using mediatomb.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not too sure. I suspect that ffmpeg is not transcoding fast enough and your TV just loops when it reaches the end. If there is no way to make mediatomb buffer a bit before it sends the stream, I would give http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/ a shot. It's the best DLNA media server I've used and you can force it to transcode to AC3 quite easily.

P.S.
I know it's called "PS3" media server, but it now has support for all sorts of devices. It is also very easy to create a device profile if your is not supported out of the box.